# chef server webui not working

Tags: ubuntu, chef-infra, configuration-management

I have download and installed `chef-server-core_12.x` DPKG package on `ubuntu 13.x`

`chef-server-ctl reconfigure` ran successfully

but when i try URL `http://chef.example.com` i get following page saying `chef server API` thats all, i didn't find any login info etc anywhere. How do i get webui interface, is there anything i missed?

```
Chef Server API

This is the main endpoint for all of the Chef API's. In general, none of these have any HTML representations, and the vast majority of them require that you are sending properly authenticated requests. So while it's neat that you came to visit, you probably won't find what you are looking for here.

You can manage your organization's infrastructure interactively using the Chef Management Console
```

Here is there services status

```
root@example.com# chef-server-ctl status
run: bookshelf: (pid 29813) 308s; run: log: (pid 29205) 339s
run: nginx: (pid 29967) 305s; run: log: (pid 29553) 316s
run: oc_bifrost: (pid 29574) 313s; run: log: (pid 28940) 358s
run: oc_id: (pid 29610) 313s; run: log: (pid 29012) 347s
run: opscode-erchef: (pid 29915) 306s; run: log: (pid 29202) 339s
run: opscode-expander: (pid 29705) 310s; run: log: (pid 29069) 341s
run: opscode-expander-reindexer: (pid 29773) 308s; run: log: (pid 29071) 341s
run: opscode-solr4: (pid 29658) 311s; run: log: (pid 29066) 341s
run: postgresql: (pid 29561) 314s; run: log: (pid 28605) 379s
run: rabbitmq: (pid 27631) 396s; run: log: (pid 27630) 396s
run: redis_lb: (pid 29498) 320s; run: log: (pid 29448) 322s
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting in Chef Server 12 (side note, you installed a pre-release test version, please don't confuse this for a final release) the web interface is a paid, premium feature. You can install it via [`chef-server-ctl install opscode-manage`](http://docs.getchef.com/ctl_chef_server.html#install). It is free up to 25 nodes or for the first 30 days, after that you should check the current Premium Chef pricing details.

Comment: You are right! i have download enterprise version by mistake, I have `uninstall` it and install `opensource` version! Thanks a lot

Comment: No, you didn't. Chef Server 12 removes the difference between the old "Open Source" and "Enterprise" versions. Now there is just a single Chef Server. The old, free web interface has been deprecated for a while and has been removed in Chef Server 12. See https://coderanger.net/chef-webui/ for more info on that.

Comment: I have install `chef-server_11.1.3-1_amd64.deb` and everything works! i don't care about `12` because i am learning and it is not important at this point

Comment: If you are learning, you shouldn't use the old web interface since, as stated before, it is deprecated and removed in the next version.

Comment: Once you do the chef-server-ctl install opscode-manage remember to do a opscode-manage-ctl reconfigure or it'll appear like nothing has changed.