# Chef Infra Server does not have a login?

Tags: chef-infra

I've just deployed a chef infra server on Ubuntu 18.04 (I'm trying learn). Following the documentation at chef.io, I've reconfigured chef and then installed the opscode management console. But when I browse to my VM I get a message saying:

"Are you looking For the Chef Infra Server?
Hello! It looks like you were trying to browse to your Chef Infra Server.
Most users interact with the Chef Infra Server using Knife or other tooling you can learn about at Learn Chef Rally.

You can access the server programmatically with the Chef Infra Server API. To learn how to do this, head over to our API Documentation pages."

I was expecting a login that I would be able to enter my organization with. What am I missing that I can't login to my infra node through a browser?

Comment: This seems to be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516289/chef-server-webui-not-working).

Answer (score 2):

you have to install the ui is an addon.
To install it you must run:

```
sudo chef-server-ctl install chef-manage  
sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure
sudo chef-manage-ctl reconfigure
sudo chef-manage-ctl reconfigure --accept-license
```

From the 25 nodes it will add a banner that you must buy a license to have support. This does not generate any limitation in adding more nodes and does not restrict any functionality, it is just a warning.

The cinc version completely open source and compatible with chef will be available soon, I am attaching the link https://cinc.sh/

Best Regards

Comment: It's worth noting that [Chef Manage](https://docs.chef.io/manage/) is deprecated and replaced by [Chef Automate](https://docs.chef.io/automate/). **Cinc** is interesting!

Comment: It's true, the new ui is automated that includes compliance and lifecycle with habitat. But it only has the trial and the new chef license does not deliver more binaries. I think that cinc is from chef like centos to redhat. The best option to avoid having to license is cinc, but it is still in process!!,We have to support the community !!

Answer (score 0):

check chef-manage is installed or not then reconfigure it "opscode-manage-ctl reconfigure"